# How to take the sum of squares in java?

Tags: java

So I am a beginner in java and am just learning the loop concept. One of my assignments is to modify this code below so that it prints out the sum of the squares of the values, rather than just the sum of the values:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
System.out.println("Separate with spaces");
System.out.println("Code sums from first to second");
int first = scan.nextInt();
int second = scan.nextInt();
int sum = 0;
for(int i = first; i <= second; i++)
{
sum += (i);
}
System.out.print("Sum from "+ first +" to " + second );
System.out.println(" is " + sum);`
```

Apparently I only have to modify one line of this code. I tried:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
System.out.println("Separate with spaces");
System.out.println("Code sums from first to second");
int first = scan.nextInt();
int second = scan.nextInt();
int sum = 0;
for(int i = first; i <= second; i++)
{
sum += (i^2);
}
```

where I thought if you just added the i^2 value inside of the parenthesis it would work, but it did not. Any help on how I do this/any help on understanding how a loop works would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i*i, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not exponentiation. See [Java Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: I can give i*i a try. But where in the code would that go? Would it go inside the loop or where I tried i^2 ?

Comment: I got it, what the system wanted was i*i  following sum +=. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Also have in mind sum += (Math.pow(i, 2)); for cases you want power larger than 2

Comment: Oh cool, never knew I could do that either. Thanks anaxin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments said,

change `i^2` to `i*i`

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
System.out.println("Separate with spaces");
System.out.println("Code sums from first to second");
int first = scan.nextInt();
int second = scan.nextInt();
int sum = 0;
for(int i = first; i <= second; i++)
{
sum += (i*i);
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the formula of sum of squares of n terms here and subtracting first one I had used n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 formula here with out no loop performance o(1)

```
sum = (second*(second+1)*((2*second)+1))/6 - (first*(first+1)*((2*first)+1))/6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
sum += (i);
```

to

```
sum += (i*i);
```